# Are path components necessarily open?

Tags: general-topology

In an arbitrary topological space, do path components have to be open? I don't think that they do, but I can't think of a counter example.

Comment: Consider a typical example where a set is connected by not path-connected.

Comment: The union of the graph of $y=\sin(1/x)$ with $\{0\}\times [-1,1]$ is a counterexample, right?

Comment: Right. If you only consider $x\in(0,1]$, then that topological space is even compact. @GTonyJacobs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple counterexample is $\mathbb{Q}$.  The (path-)components are single points, which are not open.

Comment: Ah great example. Thank you!